Graduate Texts like Vakil's Rising Sea (for any subject)
This is a fairly broad question. I self-study math texts (with weekly tutoring by, currently, a post doc algebraic geometer). So far, I've covered areas including analysis, differential geometry, algebraic topology, homological algebra at the graduate level. I've always chosen texts that have the best exposition--Rotman, Tu and Axler are favorite authors.
But I've never worked on any text like Vakil's. He rarely proves anything for you, instead gently pulling you along curated problems until you realized that you've proved the important results yourself (the hints are crucial though). There's never more than 1-2 pages without problems--learning is an active process.
Are there any other texts out there with a remotely similar teaching style? I'm primarily interested in pure math, but open to any suggestions at the graduate level including areas that I haven't touched yet (e.g. number theory).
PS: I had trouble choosing tags for this one, open to suggestions.
Update note: in general, any text that has 10+ pages without exercises probably shouldn't be recommended. A major plus of Vakil's style is you're immediately exposed to exercises for each concept so you get immediate feedback about whether you understand it.

I am not sure how "similar" the style is, but I can recommend all lecture notes by James Milne. See here for the impressive list of course notes. There are always exercises within, and a two hour exam and so on.

Fairly good suggestion! When I was less math mature I tried Milne's Galois Theory text and the style was a little too advanced for me at the time. I should try him again for a number theory text.
